# Whats the best way to achieve this grid layout in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, grid

Considerations:

- I don't know where the big cards will be
- The data comes from a cms so there could be less cards or more and in different orders
- I tried css grid but i had issues spanning the big cards because I don't know their location in the grid
- It would be ideal if each card could specify its size (whether it is big or normal)

I reckon I could push back on some of the above, but the above would be the most ideal outcome. If I have to force the layout to be: Big card and 4 small cards, 4 small cards, 4 small cards and 1 big card - and repeat that layout then maybe that's what I have to do?

[image: Layout grid design]

Comment: I have just found a property called: `grid-column: span 2;` and `grid-row: span 2;` which possibly allows this. I am working on a prototype now.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* height of one row */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
/* your pattern repeat each 18 elements */
.grid-container > :nth-child(18n + 1) {
  grid-area: span 2 / span 2; /* 2 cols, 2 rows for (1)  */
}
.grid-container > :nth-child(18n + 12){
  grid-area: span 2 / 3 / auto / span 2; /* 2 cols, 2 rows and start at column 3 for (12)  */
}


/* irrelevant styles */
.grid-container {
  counter-reset: div;
}
.grid-container > div {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.grid-container>div:before {
  counter-increment: div;
  content: counter(div);
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```